# Show ajax retrieved HTML inside a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i am looking to use ajax to retrieve table data in a web app i am building how ever i am running into a few issues

the ajax and the div work correctly however what i am chasing is inside the div to have the html code display i am using the below

```
    <script>
    function webapp_get_customers(){
       $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: '/limitless/cu.php',
       dataType: 'html'
      }).done(function( data ) {
      $('#webapp_get_customers').html(data);
      });
    }   
    </script>       


    <div id='webapp_get_customers'>the data on cu.php is displayed here</div>
```

with the above code it when viewing the source code in a browser it doesn't show the html table on cu.php i am hoping to get the below when browsing the source in a browser

```
<div id='webapp_get_customers'>
 <table>
  <tr><td>some data inside the cu.php page</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call your function `webapp_get_customers` in your code.

For example:

```
<script>
    function webapp_get_customers(){
       $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: '/limitless/cu.php',
       dataType: 'html'
      }).done(function( data ) {
      $('#webapp_get_customers').html(data);
      });
    }   
    webapp_get_customers();
    </script>       


    <div id='webapp_get_customers'>the data on cu.php is displayed here</div>
```

Comment: have removed xy, however the problem is not with loading the div but whats inside the div when viewing the source code

Comment: i want the div to have the echoed out code from cu.php

Comment: You should see if you error is in PHP or JS. So you could put console.log(data) to show your data received from server below of $('webapp_get_customers').html(data);. So you could know if you error is in server side.

Comment: made those changes and the data that's returned in the log is what i want to be displayed on the page in the source all i see is <div id='webapp_get_customers'></div> but when u see the page in the browser it has the table in it i want the browser to add the html table code between the div so it can be seen in the source

Comment: You could see the changes using the inspector of elements because the DOM is changed (in real time) but your source code is a file static (so it not change). You can use Firefox or Chrome/Chromium console (I don't know in IE).